# add line-height in @font-face

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Is there any way to add `line-height` in `@font-face` instead of `:root`, `body`, `*`, `div` & other elements?

I have multiple fonts used in web app. For example, we used Lato & Roboto fonts. If Lato font is applied I need to give `line-height: 1.4em`, If Roboto font is applied I need to give `line-height: 1.6em`. Is there any way to add `line-height` in `@font-face` or any other tricks?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: myFont;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/tangerine/v11/IurY6Y5j_oScZZow4VOxCZZMprNA4A.woff2) format('woff2');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 40px;
}

div {
  font-family: myFont;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
</p>
```

Comment: no, but use the `font` shorthand where you can specify the font and the line-height at the same time

Comment: @TemaniAfif `font` shorthand property is also not working in `@font-face` https://jsfiddle.net/09Lc2whv/

Comment: No, it will not work inside font-face. I mean inside the element so that you define both font-family and line-height at the same time

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is :

```
font : (font-size)/(line-height) (font-family)
```

this one line is equivalent to:

```
font-size : ....
line-height:....
font-family:....
```

you still need to use src though

Comment: `font` shorthand property is also not working in `@font-face` https://jsfiddle.net/09Lc2whv/